# Referencing the Activity inside its module

Tags: android, dagger-2

How do I use the new `AndroidInjector.inject` and still be able to provide an Activity instance inside an Activity Module? The Dagger docs don`t make it clear  how to archive this.

The use case is the following: I have an Activity Module which provides a Presenter to my Activity, but the Presenter needs a reference to the Activity.
I used to have something like

```
@Inject Presenter presenter;

public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ((CustomApplication) getApplicationContext())
       .getAppComponent()
       .plus(new ActivityModule(this));
}
```

Can someone can point me to a sample that uses `AndroidInjector.inject(this)` instead and allow the reference of the Activity inside the Dagger 2 module?

Comment: i am not familiar with dagger but maybe `weakreference` could help you reference an Activity.

Comment: It`s not a case for WearReference. The problem is to get a reference at all. The one creating a new instance of the module is the Dagger library with that I need to have access inside the module to an Activity where it belongs.

Comment: I'm struggling to get hold of activity ref in my @Module, as well. Dagger 1/2 look very painful to integrate, as I need to replace my roboguide with a di.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Dagger 2 Github issue 615](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/615)

The instance of your Activity is automatically provided, just pass it as a parameter in your module methods.

Example:

```
@Provides
@ActivityScope
public providePresenter(ActivityA activity) {
    return new PresenterA(activity);
}
```

You'll now be able to abstract simple modules. Your presenter can be constructor injected too.

This actually cutout a lot of code from all my modules.

Comment: Good spotting!  I didn't notice the Github issue and was trying to attempt a solution myself

Comment: I by chance came across the issue, showed my hacky solution and then was gifted a response that, like I said cutout a ton of code, easily 50% of my dagger code. It sucks that the information isn't more visible for people. However the latest releases of dagger have been huge advancements so we can't be too hard on them.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jon! That solves the problem. It just have a downside that my Module knows the Activity implementation and not the View interface. Any workaround this?

Comment: Well I mean, before your module was actually saving your​ activity. This way it is only passing it. I would guess you can still ask for the View interface and as long as the activity implements it, the graph should pass it in all the same. Never tried though.

Comment: Using the last notation `@Binds abstract BaseActivity activity(...)`, how did you manage the case when an `BaseActivity` injected class can be used in many activites? I got an `BaseActivity` is bound multiple times: ...

Comment: That is just something I do, it could be a bad idea. It works for me. Basically every activity provides it's BaseActivity to the graph. Meaning any Activity scoped objects that need an Activity can just use that instead of having a bunch of abstractions for every object for each activity. Also I have base modules, that an activity module will include, and provide the BaseActivity for it to use for Fragment Manager, Activity Extras etc... I use BaseActivity as a Activity Context replacement for the most part.

Comment: @oldergod Apparently I had things setup completely wrong, yet completely working. And now I have a lot of refraction in my future. Based a lot of stuff in the misconception that the fact it builds and runs means it was right.

Comment: @oldergod hoping for a little confirmation. Came across your question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43103956/3720591 and think we both were tripped up on the same thing. Specifically with the structuring of the recent dagger android example? I'm pretty sure I had things close to correct before and the error you mentioned was not something that meant my setup was incorrect? Not that I'm egotistical, I've just been falling thru a wormhole trying to figure it out for a few days now lol.

Comment: @JonMerritt I think I got mostly confused by the doc because up to 2.9, my `ActivityModule` would have been added into my `ActivityComponent`. The doc uses the same naming and put a `ActivityModule` (which has nothing to do with my own activity module) inside the `ApplicationComponent` which made my head explose I suppose. I am not sure your solution was wrong actually.

Comment: @JonMerritt I think the `@ActivityScope @Binds abstract BaseActivity activity(MyActivity activity);` is helpful. It just should not be put into the module linked with the parent component but inside a module added into the subcomponent.

Comment: @oldergod That's very good news. I think we did have the same issue and just tripped over it at different points. Not at all your fault but your comment threw me, for a while. Made me question my reality even. Just too be totally sure, if I put up a skeleton app on GitHub and post the link, mind looking over it, just for a fresh set of eyes?

Comment: @JonMerritt I'd be glad to. I did one as well actually: https://github.com/oldergod/dagger-android-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/dagger/demo

Comment: @oldergod I hodged it together from another project, so it may seem disjointed. But I think it shows the different cases well enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139637/discussion-between-jon-merritt-and-oldergod).