# Multiple @Binds with same return class but different key

Tags: android, dagger-2

All the following are used with dagger 2.10 and `dagger.android` package.

Say I have a class I'd like to inject in multiple activities.

```
public class DemoSharedClass {
  Activity activity;

  @Inject public DemoSharedClass(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }
}
```

Then, using the latest Dagger APIs, my classes are defined as

```
public class DemoActivity extends DaggerActivity {
  @Inject DemoSharedClass demoSharedClass;

  // ...
}

public class Demo2Activity extends DaggerActivity {
  @Inject DemoSharedClass demoSharedClass;

  // ...
}
```

Each activity has its module and subcomponent define as (exactement the same for `Demo2Activity`)

```
@Module(subcomponents = DemoActivitySubcomponent.class)
public abstract class DemoActivityModule {
  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ActivityKey(DemoActivity.class)
  abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>
    bindDemoActivityInjectorFactory(DemoActivitySubcomponent.Builder builder);

  // This is set so SharedClass can be injected using its constructor
  // There is the same in Demo2ActivityModule
  @Binds abstract Activity bindActivity(DemoActivity demoActivity);
}

@Subcomponent
public interface DemoActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<DemoActivity> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<DemoActivity> {}
}
```

Finally, the app component is defined as

```
@Component(modules = {
    ApplicationModule.class,
    AndroidInjectionModule.class,
    DemoActivityModule.class,
    Demo2ActivityModule.class,
})
interface DemoApplicationComponent {
  DemoApplication injectApplication(DemoApplication application);
}
```

Now, I get this error when I build the project:

```
Error:(11, 11) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.app.Activity is bound multiple times:
@Binds android.app.Activity dagger.demo.DemoActivityModule.bindActivity(dagger.demo.DemoActivity)
@Binds android.app.Activity dagger.demo.Demo2ActivityModule.bindActivity(dagger.demo.Demo2Activity)
```

I get the error, and I think this is because they are in the same scope, the app component.

I thought about creating a common module to both DemoSubcomponents which would look something like the following but with similar error.

```
@Module
public abstract class SharedClassModule {
  @Binds abstract Activity bindContext(DemoActivity demoActivity);
  @Binds abstract Activity bindContext(Demo2Activity demo2Activity);
}
```

Question: how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Are you building DemoApplicationComponent inside you application class or some where else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a separate binding on each Subcomponent:

```
@Module interface DemoActivitySubcomponentModule {
  @Binds abstract Activity bindContext(DemoActivity demoActivity);
  // ...other bindings unique to DemoActivity and not DemoActivity2
}

@Subcomponent(modules={DemoActivitySubcomponentModule.class})
public interface DemoActivitySubcomponent extends 
    AndroidInjector<DemoActivity> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<DemoActivity> {}
}
```

Because of `@BindsInstance Builder seedInstance(DemoActivity)` in [AndroidInjector.Builder](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjector.java#L74), which Dagger calls in [`AndroidInjector.Builder.create()`](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/1da5e7b2836619f3051901c8699d2a1b07c0c871/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjector.java#L61) from [DispatchingAndroidInjector](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DispatchingAndroidInjector.java#L79), Dagger does know how to provide a DemoActivity instance at least. However, there's no built-in binding between DemoActivity and Activity (or Context), so the binding has to be made on the subcomponent instead of the component. By putting the module with that binding on the appropriate `@Subcomponent`, you can ensure that within each respective subcomponent the `Activity` binding goes to the correct type that Dagger knows about.

Note that the `@Binds @IntoMap @ActivityKey(...)` binding in DemoActivityModule still needs to go onto the ApplicationComponent, so the ApplicationComponent can determine which subcomponent to create from the class of the Activity being injected. You specifically want the new DemoActivitySubcomponentModule to go onto DemoActivitySubcomponent so that it makes the Activity-to-DemoActivity in a place where DemoActivity2Subcomponent can't see it.

As a side note, the problem you're seeing is the conflict between the two bindings to `Activity`, which happen in the same component. It's not quite right to say the same scope, because (though you might choose to add a scope annotation like @ActivityScope to each subcomponent) there is no scope annotation that would help you here. The `seedInstance` will apply only within each currently-unscoped subcomponent, which will combine with bindings in the ancestor components as well as the subcomponent-specific modules.

Comment: Thank you. I am curious though why in the doc, the subcomponent's corresponding module is added to the application component in step 3 here: https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#injecting-activity-objects Shouldn't it be added into its corresponding subcomponent's module list as shown in your answer?

Comment: No, there are two separate Components going on here, and one module goes in each. The _Application_ component (`@Singleton`) needs to have the `@IntoMap` multibinding that allows the Application component to create the correct subcomponent. If you didn't need a general Activity or Context (just casts from YourActivity), you could get away with ignoring the other module. But as long as you do need that Activity or Context, it'll have to go in a component where YourActivity or DemoActivity is bound, so it'll have to go in a separate module on the subcomponent.

Comment: Thank you. Allow me to reiterate: in the doc, the subcomponent's corresponding module goes into the application component `@Component(modules = {..., YourActivityModule.class}) interface YourApplicationComponent {}`, why? Why isn't set in the subcomponent directly? `@Subcomponent(modules = ...)
 public interface YourActivitySubcomponent`. That was part of my confusion and lead to my asking this question here.

Comment: Each Component gets its own list of modules. The outer Application component requires a module that matches the Fragment to the subcomponent that injects it: you're telling Dagger which subcomponent it needs to create. The Activity subcomponent may need modules that express its custom Activity-specific bindings: you're telling Dagger what it needs to put into the subcomponent. The doc lists the former, which expresses a binding that always exists for `dagger.android` to work. The latter is only necessary here because your subcomponent needs a binding that can't be installed in the Application.

Comment: I finally get it. Thank you very much for the clear explanation.

Comment: Glad to help! Ah, I _just_ realized I should have picked a different module name. That's entirely my fault. I'll fix that now.